# datatable.compute - using aggegrate inside IIF

Tags: c#

i'm trying to learning how to use datatable compute expression

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A",typeof(int));
var r = dt.NewRow();
r["A"] = 50;
dt.Rows.Add(r);

var s = dt.NewRow();
s["A"] = 3;
dt.Rows.Add(s);

Response.Write(dt.Compute("IIF(true,Sum(A),10)", "").ToString());
```

but i get this error "Cannot evaluate. Expression 'System.Data.FunctionNode' is not an aggregate."

any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an aggregate function in a conditional statement.

The correct code would be :

```
Response.Write(dt.Compute("Sum(A)", "").ToString());
```